# Time Delay between Each Task Rxjava Android

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-android

I have to schedule same `observable` repeatedly for `N` number of times with `M` seconds delay between each `observable`:

**O1**____1sec____**O2**____1sec____**O3**____1sec____**O4**(completed)

Notice no delay between start and ending observable,

```
Observable<Precious> result = <~> // hidden for brevity (it's just a long time consuming observable that can take suppose up to 10 seconds or more)

Observable.timer(M,TimeUnit.SECONDS).compose(x -> result).take(N).subscribe();
```

Problem Here is `result` observable that is doing expensive network calls, will it timout itself after timer expires , or we have to tell it to do so , if so how?

Comment: I din't get your question clearly but are you worried about the fact that your first observable is emitting faster than your 2nd observable can consume?

Comment: Also, `compose(x -> result)` will throw away `x`; it's as if you wrote `x.take(N).subscribe()`. Do you need to re-subscribe to the observable? with a timeout? Have you looked at `retry`? If this doesn't seem relevant, could you expand your question with more context?

Comment: sorry for late reply , @RickSanchez exactly i am worried about the same reason as you've mentioned, @Tassos , well i don't want it's value i just want its timely calling behavior you can say that calling in `while(N != 0){dosomething(); N--; Thread.sleep(M);} `

Comment: @TassosBassoukos retry will result in calling onComplete for each call i guess ?

Comment: @Mr.Z - no, only one onComplete will be delivered downstream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination  of concatMap to concat the observables, and Delay to delay the emission of every one

```
/**
 * Another elegant solution it would be to create an observable with the list of items, and then use
 * concatMap to pass all items from the first observable to the second, then this second observable
 * can be created used delay operator afterwards.
 */
@Test
public void delayObservablesWithConcatMap() {
    Observable.from(Arrays.asList(Observable.just(1), Observable.just(2),Observable.just(3)))
            .concatMap(s -> s.delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            .subscribe(n -> System.out.println(n + " just emitted..."),
                    e -> {
                    },
                    () -> System.out.println("Everybody emitt!"));
    new TestSubscriber().awaitTerminalEvent(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

You can see more examples of delay here  https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/utils/ObservableDelay.java

Answer (score 0):

To space out items from obsevable `source` so that they're emitted every N seconds, use the following pattern:

```
source.zipWith(Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (src, dummy) -> src)
```

Caveat here is that if your source observable takes more time than the interval, then the items get queued up.

Now that I've re-read your question and clarifications, I think what you need is this:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.switchMap(dummy -> result)
```

This will unsubscribe and resubscribe to the `result` observable every 1 second. It will only workif your `result` observable cancels network calls on unsubscription.